# What are the four Forest Kingdom bears for?

Tags: a-world-of-keflings

In the Forest Kingdom of *A World of Keflings*, you can find four bears on an island to the southeast. I've been through the entire story and didn't run across a quest that calls for their use. They aren't considered a 'decoration' for a house. I've tried combining them into different patterns with no luck as well.

Does anyone know what they are used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrange the bears into a square to automatically make something bear-related

Here is the combination:

Top row:

> Secret Bear, Covert Bear

Bottom row:

> Enigmatic Bear, Discreet Bear

Comment: @Blake Yeah, Cobert would not approve. ;p

Answer (score 1):

Keep rearranging them in a 2x2 square. When you get the right combination, you'll know. There are only 24 possible combinations.

Comment: Since all the bears have names, can you be more specific about their setup?

Answer (score 0):

Take The Bears And put the Secret Bear and the Covert Bear beside each other then take the other bears on bottem right below the Secret bear and the Covert bear.                                                                                                        Then you'll get something called "BEARS!!!"